# Determining the index of an Item on a Form (J2ME)

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui

Given an `Item` that has been appended to a `Form`, whats the best way to find out what index that item is at on the Form?

`Form.append(Item)` will give me the index its initially added at, but if I later insert items before that the index will be out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the best I could come up with:

```
private int getItemIndex(Item item, Form form) {
    for(int i = 0, size = form.size(); i < size; i++) {
        if(form.get(i).equals(item)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I haven't actually tested this but it should work, I just don't like having to enumerate every item but then there should never be that many so I guess its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are just two ways to do this, since the API does not have an `indexOf(Item)` method:

1. You update the index you get when you add an `Item`. So when you insert another `Item` before other items, you'll have to update the indices of those items. You could keep some kind of shadow-array for this, but that seems a bit overkill.
2. You loop through all the items of a form using the `size` and `get` methods of `Form`.